# UITableView refresh works incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2, refresh

My pull to refresh feature actually work, but it doesn't reload the data for the first cell. I mean if I refresh the table cells are mixed. First cell doesn't change but new cell that should be newly come to the first cell shown in the below cells. If I close and open the app I can reach the data in order, but I couldn't refresh the data in order if I use pull to refresh.

```
var page : Int = 1
var refresher: UIRefreshControl!
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    refresher = UIRefreshControl()

    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

    refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newPollsTableViewController.refresh), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)


            data_request() 
}
```

this is my data_request() func:

```
func data_request(){
    let user_id = Data[0].valueForKey("user_id") as? String!

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://..../perspective/\(user_id!)/page/"+"\(page)" )!

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    self.page = self.page + 1


    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData


    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (let data, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        var json: AnyObject?

        do {
            json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: [])
        } 
        catch {
            return
        }

        guard let data_array = json as? NSArray else {
            return
        }

        for i in 0..<data_array.count
        {
            if let add = data_array[i] as? NSDictionary
            {   
                self.obj.append(Obj(data:add))
            }
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in   
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
     }
    task.resume()  
}
```

and I call the my refresh func when I pull the refresh the table.

```
func refresh() {
        self.page = 1
        data_request()
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
}
```

Each time I pull the refresh the table it enters the `data_request()` func but it doesn't update the table.

Comment: Keep in mind the order will always reflect the data source's order. Put a breakpoint just before reloadData and look at data source. Your problem should be there.

Comment: You have 3 calls to `return` between loading the data and reloading the table view. Are you hitting any of those `return` statements? Use the debugger. This is what it is for. Step through the code and see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Strange things are happening to the data source, try to modify your [caching policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/enum/c:@E@NSURLRequestCachePolicy)

From:

```
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
```

To:

```
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
```

Comment: I will try, I solved by adding self.obj.removeAll() just before the self.obj.append(Obj(data:add))

Comment: Good news, be careful with you data source :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding `self.obj.removeAll()` just before the `self.obj.append(Obj(data:add))`